# Where should I report a segmentation fault error I encountered in Lua and LuaJit?

Tags: lua, segmentation-fault, luajit, bug-reporting

I am playing a little with the (somewhat idiotic) idea of improving a function through a genetic algorithm and the manipulation of the output of that function's `string.dump`, and I had a segmentation fault error popping out in luajit and then in Lua too.

Where can I report that error and the code that caused it, given that I only have a Stack Overflow and a Reddit account?

Comment: Good news, people. It popped out in Lua too.

Comment: It's now a Segfault in Lua and a Bus error in Luajit. Halp.

Comment: What makes you think that this is an error that should be reported to Lua or LuaJIT's developers? You're manipulating a function's binary representation. Neither library makes any statement that they will accept *any* binary, regardless of its source. Indeed, they only work with binaries that they themselves generate. It seems to me that you are on your own on this.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas `loadstring` (or `load` in newer versions) only accepts lua code strings or 'true' output from `string.dump`, and returns `nil` otherwise, so I guess what is passed as the argument is validated and controlled before trying to run it.

Comment: "*so I guess what is passed as the argument is validated and controlled before trying to run it.*" If you pass a precompiled chunk to that function, it will do no "validation" or "controlling" of any kind. It will *assume* that the bytes represent legitimate compiled Lua bytecode. Lua is fault-tolerant when passed Lua source strings. Lua is not fault-tolerant of being passed bytecode.

Comment: @Nicolas Bolas it's strings anyway, how does it know it's one or the other?

Comment: I imagine it detects the presence of initial bytes which wouldn't be legitimate characters in the Lua character set. But that's essentially irrelevant; what matters is that it can tell the difference, and it behaves differently in those cases.

Comment: All right then, closing the question.